# How does an airplane owner correct an airplane misidentification showing up on FlightAware?

Tags: flight-tracking

I have a friend in Pennsylvania with a plane in Pennsylvania. FlightAware is currently showing his airplane in the Bahamas, when it is not. He wants to know whom to contact to get this corrected. I'm assuming it's in some database being use by both FlightAware and FlightRadar24.

Comment: https://flightaware.com/about/contact/

Comment: Another possibility is that the database is correct, but the transponder on the aircraft in the Bahamas is using the wrong aircraft address.

Comment: Maybe it was repo'ed?  Like the tv show! Just kidding.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of it:

[contact flightaware directly](https://flightaware.com/about/contact/)
https://flightaware.com/about/contact/

Comment: FlightAware says they just use data from the FAA.

Answer (score 1):

I posted the same question in a Facebook page maintained by the FAA. I got a lot of possible answers:

- Controller fat-fingered an N number
- Person fat-fingered a number during ADS-registration
- Plane is actually in the Bahamas (not the case here)
- As for contacting FlightAware, one person wrote: "I had one like that, contacted Flightaware and they told me most likely ATC typed in the N number incorrectly, and nothing Flightaware can do about it."
- An instructor wrote, "I was pondering something similar, and I suspect it is due to some ADS-B transmitters (like the GDL-82) having "Anonymous Mode" which allows the user to use a randomly generated ADS-B identifier. This theoretically reduces "Big Brother's" ability to track and individual. My guess is that the randomly generated identifier accidentally collides with a real one. Check out my student's plane that magically teleported from the PNW to SOCAL and back just before Christmas"
- A pilot wrote, "It'll take care of itself. I've had planes show enroute when they were in the hangar. It's just a glitch in the faa computer from which flightaware and others get their data."